# What's wrong with generating private keys in this way?

Tags: security, private-key

Mostly out of curiosity, but if you wanted to generate your own ethereum private/public key pair, and NOTE use anyone else's code, is there anything that's wrong with doing it like this:

```
const validChars = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let key = ""

for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    let rand = validChars[Math.floor(Math.random() * validChars.length)];
    key += rand
}

//key is now a random string of 64 valid ETH characters
console.log(key)
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, yes, a private key is just a random number. That said, I see two things wrong with your code:

1. Be careful to use a random number generator that's meant for cryptographic security. In Node.js, you would want to use `crypto` (e.g. `crypto.randomBytes(32)`).
2. Not all 256-bit random numbers are valid private keys. The private key has to be less than `0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141`, which is the `n` value for the elliptic curve being used (secp256k1). It also has to be greater than 0. (Thanks @Ismael.)

Comment: Also `0` is not a valid private key.